# I encountered a problem while doing Npm build in vanilla js. Please take a look

Tags: javascript, npm-scripts, npm-build

I was learning JavaScript and kind of ran into problem that said like this :
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hStM1.png)

Here's my package.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciaeO.png)

So to explain,  this is my vanilla js where i have installed parcel

Vs code Terminal

- npm i parcel --save-dev
- npm run start
- npm run build

theen this error pops up. I don't know if i added enough screenshots or details to make someone understand my problem. If you do have a solution help please.

Edit : I also tried,

"main" : "17th.html" as suggested which then threw new error saying the extension should be of .js

Final edit : So , i deleted "main" and then it worked like a charm. Dont know why it works but it works . If someone could explain why it works then i would be very grateful.

I was expeccting a successful build

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212).

Comment: You need to get a monospaced font going on, mate.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thankyouu. I will remember it. This is my first time on stack overflow.

Comment: @OFRBG hi, thankyou . I am using operator mono rightnow. It looks nice on the coding screen but on terminal somehow it looks bad. I don't know why.

Comment: Well, in your package.json, you have `parcel 17th.html` as your start command, but you have `17th.js` as your main. That discrepancy might cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was just deleting

```
main: "filepath"
```

You can also  organize this better by having a src folder and moving all your html files there, a js folder which contains all your js files and a css folder that contains all your css files.

Below is my paackage.json which builds as intended.

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "stackoverflow example",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "author": "my name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.6.2",
    "parcel": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "npm:@gsap/shockingly@^3.10.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thankyou. Umm deleted the " main " and it build successfuly. I don't know why it works , but it does. Also , is it safe ? Since we are deleting the 'main' ?

Comment: They don't have the main on the documentation here: https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/ but they do have the source as it's own property.

Answer (score 0):

Entry should be an html file like

```
main: "17th.html"
```

Comment: Hi thankyou , but then the new error pops up saying the file extensions should be of  .js , .mjs or .cjs.